# TikZ node within another

Tags: tikz-pgf

i want to create a node in TikZ that consists of two parts. So far I have tried the following

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\tikzstyle{splitbox} = [rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=2cm, text centered, text width=3cm, draw=black, rectangle split part fill={white, lightgray}]

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=4cm]
\node (node) [splitbox] {\nodepart{one} The whole thing
\nodepart{two} A part of it}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This gives me a result that looks like

[image: Image 1]

So far so good. But actually i want it to look more like

[image: Image 2]

Does anyone have an Idea, how I can achive that? Have been googeling for hours. The "part" nodepart should always be, where my arrow starts.
Thanks a lot for your suggestions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative solution:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,shapes,positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance=0mm, 
every node/.style = {rectangle, inner sep=0mm, outer sep=0mm,
                     align=center, minimum height=15mm},  
                    ]
\node (t) [text width=5cm] {The whole thing};
\node (b) [text width=3cm,draw,fill=lightgray, 
           below=of t] {A part of it};
\node [draw,fit=(t) (b)]    {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I have to say, that i like this one even a little better as the other suggestion, as I can connect it with my tikzstyles in the preamble...

Answer (score 4):

like this :

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=4cm]
\node [name=n1, rectangle, minimum width=5cm, minimum height=3cm,
text centered, text width=3cm, draw=black] {};

\node [name=t, rectangle, minimum width=5cm, minimum height=1.5cm,
text centered, text width=3cm, below=(0mm of n1.north)] {The whole thing};

\node [name=n2,rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1.5cm,
text centered, text width=3cm, anchor=south, above=(0cm of n1.south),
draw=black,fill=lightgray] {A part of it};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!!! This works and the output looks exactly how I want it to be. Nevertheless it produces two error messages: 


Package PGF Math Error: Unknown operator `o' or `of' (in '(0cm of n1.south)'). draw=black,fill=lightgray] (followed by: {A part of it};)



Package PGF Math Error: Unknown operator `o' or `of' (in '(0mm of n1.north)'). ... text width=3cm, below=(0mm of n1.north)] (followed by: {The whole thing};)

Comment: you need positionings : `\usetikzlibrary{shapes, positioning}`

Comment: That helped! My mistake ;)   Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

Another alternative with a unique `node` defined as a `matrix` and `matrix of nodes`:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    part/.style={draw, fill=black!30},
    whole/.style={
        matrix,
        draw,
        matrix of nodes,
        inner xsep=3mm,
        inner ysep=-.5\pgflinewidth,
        nodes={minimum height=12mm},
        row 2/.style={nodes={part}}
    }]

\node[whole] (A) {
The whole thing\\
A part of it\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you can use it on a `\node[whole]` if you add `matrix` to the style

Comment: @percusse I tested it before posting my answer and it didn't worked. Now it did. How are you controlling my computer? ;-)

Comment: With a mouse obviously; something `emacs, vim` geeks would never suspect :P